# Which modeling methods should I use to explore this new time-series data?

Tags: model, time-series, regression

Each row on the dataset is information from a machine, retrieved hourly. I don't want to use an autoregressive model like ARIMA, I'm interested in the relationship between the variables and the response variable rather that focusing on the response variable's history. I'm really just looking for some advice on how to start the data exploration portion of this project. Also looking for some modelling recommendations for this kind of focus. Thanks.